# Nested routes in Angular 14

Tags: angular

I've been struggling with getting nested routes in Angular 14. Because all similar questions on SO are for older versions of Angular and no longer work, I posted this new question for a more up-to-date answer.

I did manage to get it to work, but to help others who are facing a similar issue, I'm putting my answer below.

My issue was that when loading in the submodule like shown below, my routes wouldn't match.

My main application module:

```js
//app.module.ts
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SubModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My main routing module:

```js
// app-routing.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'beheer', loadChildren: () => import('src/sub/submodule.module').then(module => module.SubModule) },
  { path: 'somepath', component: SomeComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

```js
// sub.module.ts
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SubModuleMainComponent,
    SubContentComponent,
    SomeOtherComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SubModuleRoutingModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [SubModuleMainComponent]
})
export class SubModule {}
```

```js
// sub-routing.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
   {path: 'sub', component: SubMainComponent, children: [
    { path: '', component: SubContentComponent },
    { path: 'some-other-page', component: SomeOtherComponent },
  ]}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class SubRoutingModule {}
```

And finally, the submodule's main component which shows the routes for its own components (app.component.html also has its own router-outlet!):

```html
<!-- sub-main.component.html -->
<span>Hello world</span>
<router-outlet></router-outlet> <!-- all of the submodule's children will be displayed here -->
```

My goal: having all pages that are part of the submodule to be available from URLs like '/sub/someothercomponent', with a default page at `<baseURL>/sub`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the the routing did sort of work, just not the way I expected it to. Two things vital here are:

- The sub-routing module must be declared as .forChild whereas the main routing module must be .forRoot:

```js
//app-routing.module.ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  ...

//sub-routing.module.ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  ...
```

Using .forRoot twice does produce an error.

- Additionally, I messed up the route paths a bit. Solution:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
   {path: '', component: SubMainComponent, children: [
    { path: '', component: SubContentComponent },
    { path: 'some-other-page', component: SomeOtherComponent },
  ]}
];
...
```

My initial attempt with `'sub'` as path for the SubMainComponent caused the module to route as `<baseURL>/sub/sub/page`, but the solution is to have both the wrapper component as well as the default page have the path `''`.

`SubMainComponent` is the component that wraps its children and has the `<router-outlet>` in it. `SubContentComponent` is its default page (`<baseURL>/sub`).